# Приоритеты у разных селекторов CSS

Tags: html, css

Я заметил что при использовании разных споcобов обратиться к HTML элементу в CSS одни селекторы побеждают другие.

---

Предположим в пустом HTML документе есть параграф, которому присвоен класс `someclass`.

Псевдоселектор **p:first-class** окажется **сильнее, чем** селектор класса **.someclass**.

Теперь заменим класс `someclass` на id.

Псевдоселектор **p:first-class** окажется **слабее чем** селектор id **#someclass**.

---

Хотелось бы понять логику этих приоритетов.
Есть ли какой-нибудь справочник, может быть, таблица, наглядно демонстрирующая приоритеты одних селекторов над другими?

*(кажется, мне попадалась похожая таблица приоритетов арифметических и побитовых операций, когда я осваивал javascript)*

Comment: Есть. Первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу *Приоритеты селекторов CSS* И на хабре было хорошо расписано.

Comment: @Moonvvell, Большое спасибо, да это то что нужно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю поможет или нет:

```
*             {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,0,0 */
 li            {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,0,1 */
 li:first-line {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
 ul li         {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
 ul ol+li      {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,0,3 */
 h1 + *[rel=up]{}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,1,1 */
 ul ol li.red  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,1,3 */
 li.red.level  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,2,1 */
 #x34y         {}  /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */
 style=""          /* a=1 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 1,0,0,0 */
<HEAD>
<STYLE type="text/css">
  #x97z { color: red }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P ID=x97z style="color: green">
</BODY>
```

[Источник](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Интересный ресурс. Я правильно понимаю, что a,b,c,d - это как бы категория приоритета, a  - самая высокая, d - самая низкая? И d=2 больше d=1, а c=1 больше d=2 - верно?